# How to use layout="fill" in next.js image

Tags: next.js

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { layout } from 'next/legacy/image';

function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
      {/* left */}
      <div className="relative flex items-center h-10 cursor-pointer m-auto">
        <Image
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/Airbnb_Logo_B%C3%A9lo.svg/2560px-Airbnb_Logo_B%C3%A9lo.svg.png"
          alt="main_logo"
          fill
          className="object-contain object-left"
        />
      </div>

      {/* middle */}
      <div></div>

      {/* right */}

      <div></div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

The image doesn't deflate and doesn't eat commands. Thank you for solving it.

i tried use <Image style={{ fill }} > and

import { layout } from 'next/legacy/image';
but dosent work normally.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

It must be used in this way :

```
        <Image
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/Airbnb_Logo_B%C3%A9lo.svg/2560px-Airbnb_Logo_B%C3%A9lo.svg.png"
          alt="main_logo"
          layout="fill"
          className="object-contain object-left"
        />
```